# how do I fix subscript out of range error in vba for copying sheets between workbooks

Tags: vba

Can anybody help me with the below code in vba. on running, it shows Error 9 -Subscript out of range.

```
Sub add_sheet()

    cwb = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    booktoopen = "C:\Users\mf\Desktop\BOI Bills Ver\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open(booktoopen).Activate
    Workbooks(cwb).Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Sheets("Sheet1")
    Workbooks(booktoopen).Close savechanges = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with the workbook variables directly instead of with their names and declare all your variables properly (use `Option Explicit`!).

Also named parameters need a `:=` not just a `=` like `SaveChanges:=True`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub add_sheet()
    Dim PathToOpen As String  ' define path of the workbook
    PathToOpen = "C:\Users\mf\Desktop\BOI Bills Ver\Reports\Srikakulam.xlsx"

    Dim OpenedBook As Workbook  ' open workbook and reference it to a variable that we can use later
    Set OpenedBook = Workbooks.Open(PathToOpen)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=OpenedBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    OpenedBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```